# Can a Bare (git) repo transfer all the latest files to a new git clone?

Tags: git

Im new, and this seems like a simple question, but I can't seem to find a clear answer. If is set up a bare repo, and a new user comes along, can they do `git clone` to get access to the whole latest repository?

I'm assuming yes?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Are you just starting out using git?

Comment: Yes I am. I'm getting used to things, and sometimes some finer points (the 'duh' details) are harder to come by :).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, cloning a repo gets you the whole repo. The clone will not be bare by default.